# CSS Style Linking

Tags: css, animation, html

Is it possible to use one style for all three of my divs to make it short and simple, and keep the animation working? Any help is much appreciated.

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/db5uS/1/)

Comment: Don't provide a link to your source. *WHEN* that link dies your question will be useless to future visitors with a similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean apply the css to all three elements? If so you just need to do this:

```
.a, .b, .c {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #dbdbdb;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.a {animation-delay: 1s;
  animation: fade 1s forwards;}
.b {animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: fade 2s forwards;}
.c {animation-delay: 3s;
  animation: fade 3s forwards;}
@keyframes fade {
0%   {opacity:0;}
50%   {opacity:1;}
100% {opacity:0;}}​
```

Comment: The animation times for .a, .b and .c are different

Comment: I had no way of knowing that based on your question. I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: not my question...but yeah it was evident in the JS Fiddle example. this is now much better...+1

Comment: No problem. Normally it's better to copy the actual code in the question as well... Glad it helps!

Comment: The animation portion is still has the wrong values compared to the jsfiddle, but is otherwise correct (and better than adding an extra class like the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db5uS/6/):

```
.a {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation: fade 1s forwards;}


.b {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: fade 2s forwards;}


.c {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation: fade 3s forwards;}

.d{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #dbdbdb;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;}

@keyframes fade {
0%   {opacity:0;}
50%   {opacity:1;}
100% {opacity:0;}}​
```

And then your HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="a d"></div>
<div class="b d"></div>
<div class="c d"></div>​
```

Comment: Ditto...exactly what I did!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, since your animation attributes are all different, so they will need different classes. but you can certainly shorten your CSS by keeping all of the common attributes in their own class, like so:

```
.x {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #dbdbdb;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.a {

  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation: fade 1s forwards;
}


.b {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: fade 2s forwards;
}


.c {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation: fade 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
0%   {opacity:0;}
50%   {opacity:1;}
100% {opacity:0;}}
```

Use like so:

```
<div class="x a"></div>
<div class="x b"></div>
<div class="x c"></div>
```